# Swift - Should I be separating a struct from logic functions?

Tags: swift, struct, separation-of-concerns

I'm writing a card game.  I've seen examples where programmers will separate their `struct` from a `service`.

I'm not sure if I should also be doing the same.

But my question is -- should I be separating the struct from logical functions; or is it okay to put them together?

My code is as such:

```
// Card Model
struct FSCard {
    var type: FSCardType // enum reference
    var name: String
    var value: Int
    weak var owner: FSPlayer?  // class reference

    var description: String {
        return ("Name: \(self.name) Value: \(self.value), Type: \(self.type)")
    }
}

class FSCardAPI: NSObject {
   // static functions
   public static func filter(cards:[FSCard], type:FSCardType) -> [FSCard] 
   {
      // some code goes here ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to separate your both struct and class, especially when they only exist in one view/controller/etc and cooperate only with each other. Dividing above into two files only increases readability. When there is a lot of classes that use your model (in your case `struct FSCard`) it's advisable, because you can easily find and check your struct for reading only or modifying it.